# What is the difference between sleep() and usleep() in this ob_flush example

Tags: php

I am trying to learn the `ob_start`, `ob_flush` function and I found this code on internet

```
if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();
for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++)
{
    echo "$i<br />";

    ob_flush();
    flush();
    usleep(30000);
        // sleep(0.03);
}
```

I am trying to change the `usleep()` function which is use with microseconds to sleep (seconds) but it doesn't work as the `usleep()`.

Is there something wrong or difference between `sleep()` and `usleep()`?

Comment: I have tried your code and it works right away. It nicely draws the numbers 0-999 on the screen in 3000ms intervals.

Comment: This question is whack. OP knows the difference yet he still wishes to use fractions with `sleep()` (which won't work). Just use `usleep()`. That's what it was made for.

Comment: @davidkonrad and Gerald Schneider were right, sleep() only accept integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have figured out an answer to what you are confused about :

`sleep(0.03)` does not work because it needs an integer. `sleep(0.03)` is interpreted as `sleep(0)`.

Thats why there also is the function `usleep()` which provides sleep() in milliseconds, eg usleep(3000). And why there also is a third sleep function, `time_nanosleep()` which provides a mix of seconds and *nanoseconds*, even higher resolution.

I guess the three different functions is a result how the functions is built - demanding integers - and because the value of the largest integer is platform dependent. In 32bit the highest integer is 2147483647. In 64bit, the highest integer is 9223372036854775807.

Comment: thank you, now I know why I can't use sleep, thank alot

Answer (score 1):

The difference between sleep is  [sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) Delays the program execution for the given number of seconds and [usleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php) Delays program execution for the given number of micro seconds.

Comment: I think it is pretty clear OP is aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use fractions as a parameter for [`sleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

```
sleep(0.03);
```

Here 0.03 will be cast into an integer

```
sleep(0);
```

So PHP will sleep for 0 seconds.

If you want to sleep for fractions of seconds, you have to use [`usleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php) or [`time_nanosleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time-nanosleep.php).